# how to iterate a list in react realm database

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a list which contains the list of data with many properties. I want to iterate and read a single property in all over the list. I can able to read it by mentioning the position(For ex : list[0]) but I want to read it dynamically. How can I iterate and read it dynamically without mentioning the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this using a *map*.

```
myRealmData.map((eachRealmItem, index) => {
  // whatever you wanna do...
});
```

or using a normal *for*:

```
for (let i = 0; myRealmData.length - 1; i++) {
  let eachRealmItem = myRealmData[i];
}
```

Comment: how much ram do my phone needs to iterate 10 gb of database data? is there a way to use cursors like in mongodb so lists won't be loaded into javascript ram in runtime and instead read by chunks when needed?